# Linear Algebra quesion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

$A^{-1} - \lambda A = B^{-1} - \lambda B - \alpha v v^T$

$A, B \in S^n_+$; $v \in R^n$; $\lambda, \alpha \in R_+$. Can we solve A in term of other variables?

Comment: Is $S^n_+$ symmetric positive definite real matrices?

Comment: There are certainly sets of parameter values for which the equation produces no solution or infinitely many. Do you want just any solution if one exists?

Comment: yep, I mean both A and B are real and I am looking for a closed-form solution if exists. Thanks

Comment: @EricAuld I think $S^n_+$ means symmetric positive semi-definite real matrices? let me know if i am wrong

Comment: @user1551 sorry, you are right, i mean $\alpha vv^T$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $A$.

You will get something like: $aA^2+bA+c=0$.

Comment: What do you mean? Would you please elaborate?